# Can't resolve DNS in ASP.NET (works in console)

Tags: asp.net, dns

When I call Dns.GetHostEntry("SomeServerName") from a console application on my desktop it resolves the IP address just fine.  When I execute the same code in an ASP.NET application, also running on my desktop, I get a SocketException with the message "Unknown host".

I sense that there may be wrong with my IIS / ASP.NET installation, but I don't have the time right now to try reinstalling.

As a test, I changed the identity of the ASP.NET account in the machine.config to use my own network credentials, but that didn't make any difference.

Any ideas?

Update:

It seems I need to clarify.  I'm having problems doing network communication from ASP.NET on my workstation.  This includes trying to send emails using the SmtpClient and also trying to connect to a IBM DB2 via an ODBC connection.  These things all work fine when running in a console application.  The root cause seems to be that when the code is running under ASP.NET, DNS resolution fails, although I have no idea why.  The only difference I can think of is the security context.

Update 2:

Here are some results from running Wireshark:
When the call is made from a console application, I immediately see 2 "Standard Domain Name System Queries" being sent across the network.
When the same call is made from an ASP.NET application, after a delay of about 8 seconds, I see 3 "NetBIOS Name Service Queries" being sent across the network.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved : The antivirus program on my workstation was explicitly blocking outgoing connections from IIS, ostensibly to stop worms from spreading around the network.

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/2a8ca3c8-e1ec-490a-a7e5-5ec533080f00/

> If you pass an IP address literal to GetHostEntry it will attempt a
>   DNS reverse resolve instead of just giving you back the IP address. 
>   If the data for a successfull reverse resolve is not in your DNS
>   server, this will fail.  If you don't want this semantic (ie. no
>   reverse lookup), then use Dns.GetHostAddresses.

Comment: If this were true, both the console app and the asp.net app would fail?

Comment: Q: Why not try it (unless, of course, you *want* to require a reverse lookup). Q: Have you checked for any errors or inner exceptions (besides "unknown host")?  Q: What does nslookup show?   And remember: the debug "vhost" debug environment (which you may or may not be using) introduces additional constraints.

Comment: @Patrick J Collins - I wouldn't reinstall IIS or .Net - I don't think it would help. I honestly believe switching to GetHostAddresses() might get it working. IMHO...

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't answer my question, although I guess I wasn't precise enough.  I've updated the original question.